# Returning Polymorphic Class

Tags: function, generics, fortran, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand why one of the below is allowed by the standard while the other is not. They don't seem different except for boilerplate code to me. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something, or that there is a better way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Not allowed:

```
real :: x
class(*) :: temp

x = 4

temp = genericAssignment(x)

select type(temp)
type is(real)
    write(*,*) temp
end select

contains

function genericAssignment(a) result(b)
    class(*) :: a
    class(*) :: b

    allocate(b, source=a)
end function genericAssignment
```

Allowed:

```
Type GenericContainer
    class(*), pointer :: gen
End Type

real :: x
class(*) :: ptr
type(GenericContainer) :: temp

x = 4

temp = genericAssignment(x)

select type(ptr => temp%gen)
type is(real)
    write(*,*) ptr
end select

contains

function genericAssignment(a) result(b)
    class(*) :: a
    type(GenericContainer) :: b

    allocate(b%gen, source=a)
end function genericAssignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current standard allows both.

The "allowed" code block has a function with a non-polymorphic result, with the result of evaluating the function being assigned to a non-polymorphic variable.  This is valid Fortran 2003.

The "not allowed" block has a function with a polymorphic result, with the result of evaluating the function being assigned to a polymorphic variable.  This is valid Fortran 2008.

Note that the number of complete Fortran 2008 compiler implementations out there is small.

~~~

The function in the "not allowed" block is somewhat pointless - the code block is equivalent to:

```
real :: x
class(*) :: temp

x = 4

temp = x

select type(temp)
type is(real)
  write(*,*) temp
end select
```

Comment: Thank you for the information on Fortran 2008. My compiler does not have that feature yet then, but it is nice to know it is on the way eventually. The whole code section is pointless in the above example insofar as to do anything productive. It was only a simple example to illustrate my question. A useful version of the function would be to perform some large modification on a parent class portion of a host of children types.

Comment: For example, I deal with a host of different coordinate frames. I have a parent type(position, velocity, and acceleration), but I decided to give each coordinate frame it's own child type in order to remove the possibility of passing the wrong frame into a coordinate transform function, and also to give each child the ability to hold onto its relevant reference data. I have a function that takes a right-handed frame and returns a left-handed one. I would prefer to only have to have a single copy of the function for all children. That doesn't seem possible in fortran, without worse overhead.

Comment: Aaaaaaand.... I just figured out how to do my example in the above comment. After much longer than I'd like to admit, I realized I can just use child%parent = parentModifyingFunction() and I don't have to care about a work around for returning a polymorphic class for many cases.